# Using 'dynamic' Loops

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, vbscript

I'm not exactly a noob to VBA/VBScript, but I've never really ventured further than IF and FOR functions. 
So I wanted to know if what I am doing is the best option for one of my processes or if there is something much less complicated that I could use.

I've recently heard of recursion in my searches but have no idea what it is or does. 
My entire script has lots of rules to what can and cant happen so I'll try to explain what I need as basically as posible:

I need to get from 'A' to 'B'.

At 'A' the road splits in to so many paths (at no point after splitting do the paths cross again until reaching 'B'), I take the left most path until reaching another split in the road. At this split I again take the left most path.

This process continues until I reach a dead end or 'B', at which point I back track to the last junction, taking the next left most junction.

By continuing this process I can find all the routes that lead to 'B' and therefore workout out the shortest (from path lengths) or least complicated route from 'A' to 'B'.
I've tried to use a 'dynamic' loop for this process, and it seems to work ok.

```
Tier = 1
sLoops = 1

For j = 1 To jRow + 1       'jRow is the max number of junctions
    If j = jRow + 1 Then

        'If j > max junction, decrease tier unless tier level is 1
        If Tier <> 1 Then

            ' Change tier
            Tier = Tier - 1

            ' Reset loop to positon of previous loop
            j = Mid(sLoops, InStrRev(sLoops, "|") + 1)

            ' Remove last entry from loop list
            sLoops = Left(sLoops, InStrRev(sLoops, "|") - 1)

        End If
     Else

        'Match process (True or false)

        If match Then
            If Tier < 20 Then
                Tier = Tier + 1

                ' Add entry to loop list
                sLoops = sLoops & "|" & j

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If 'match' finds a match the tier increases unless it is past 20, 
If the tier decreases to 1 the loop ends. 
In this loop only the value j is dynamic but in my actual script I have

```
For a = b to c
```

Where a, b and c can all be adjusted to suit

Comment: Recursive functions are ones that call themselves, and your problem is a classic opportunity for recursion.  To record the path you take, you could pass a variable byref to the function, or use a global variable.  There are loads of good resources out there to explain recursive functions.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've now got a recursive function that does the same work as my loop